# Get duration between records from separate tables by date

Tags: php, mysql

This is a bit tricky to explain but let's say i have 2 tables, one for the quotes and the other for the quotes responses.

```
Table: Quotes
-----------------
id  |  name  | date(DATETIME)
1   |  foo   | 2012-09-11 16:21:18
2   |  bar   | 2012-09-11 16:48:28

Table: Responses
-----------------
quote_id  |  response  |  date(DATETIME)
1         |  blah      |  2012-09-11 16:28:42
2         |  Meh       |  2012-09-11 16:58:34
```

I'd like to get the total average response rate to the quotes based on deducting the quote date off the response date.

So i get something like 8.7 seconds average response time.

How to do that efficiently using only a MySQL query if possible?

P.S. A Quote can have multiple responses, The calculation should only consider the first response of each quote for an accurate result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This joins your Quotes to the first date in Responses and gets the AVG TIMEDIFF. This will only consider those Quotes that have Responses.

```
SELECT AVG(TIMEDIFF(b.`date`, a.`date`))
FROM Quotes a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT quote_id, MIN(`date`) as `date` 
  FROM Responses
  GROUP BY quote_id) b 
  ON (b.quote_id = a.quote_id)
```

Comment: nice solution, i tried it, it partially worked! the issue is that it only considered the first quote for the whole calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Will it work for you?

```
SELECT AVG(TIMEDIFF(b.`date`, a.`date`))
FROM Quotes a
INNER JOIN Responses b ON (b.quote_id = a.quote_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, i forgot to mention that a quote can have multiple responses, and so it should only consider the first response of each quote for the calculation.